# Convert double values of a file into a special format

Tags: java

I am still relatively new to java but the problem that I am facing right now is that I keep getting a compile time error with what I currently have.

I'm not sure if there's a special logic structure that would take existing values from the file and convert the format of the numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;

public class Music {

  // Method header
  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

    // Variable declarations
    String id;
    String artistName;
    String title;
    String releaseName;
    int year;
    double endOfFadeIn;
    double startOfFadeOut;
    double loudness;
    double duration;

    // Scanner to read input from the user
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Scanner to read in the file that the user types.
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the file: ");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
    File inFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(inFile);
    fileScan.useDelimiter(",|\\r?\\n");

    fileScan.nextLine();

    // Read from file using Scanner
    while(fileScan.hasNext()) {
      id = fileScan.next();
      System.out.println(id);
      id = formatID(id);
      System.out.println(id);
      artistName = fileScan.next();
      System.out.println(artistName);
      artistName = truncate(artistName);
      title = fileScan.next();
      System.out.println(title);
      title = truncate(title);
      releaseName = fileScan.next();
      System.out.println(releaseName);
      releaseName = truncate(releaseName);
      year = fileScan.nextInt();
      System.out.println(year);
      endOfFadeIn = fileScan.nextDouble();
      System.out.println(endOfFadeIn);
      startOfFadeOut = fileScan.nextDouble();
      System.out.println(startOfFadeOut);
      loudness = fileScan.nextDouble();
      System.out.println(loudness);
      System.out.printf("%-10s %-20s %-20s %-20s%n", id, artistName, title,
      releaseName);
    }

  }// end main

  public static String formatID(String id) {
    String newid;
    newid = id.substring(0,7) + "-" + id.substring(7,9) + "-" + id.substring(9,18);
    return newid;
  }//end formatID

  public static String truncate(String str){
    if (str.length() > 20) {
      return str.substring(0, 20-3) + "...";
    } else {
      return str;
    }
  }//end truncateStr
  public static String formatTime(double duration) {
  int days=0;
  int hours=0;
  int minutes=0;
  int seconds=0;
  String Result;
  Result = System.out.printf("%03s:%02s:%02s:%02s", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
  string.format
  System.out.printf("%03s:%02s:%02s:%02s", days, hours, minutes, seconds);

  duration = (int) duration;
  duration = (startOfFadeOut - endOfFadeIn);
  duration = Math.round(duration);
  }//end formatTime
}//end class
```

The expected result is that when the values are read in from the file the output will display the time in this format DD:HH:MM:SS.

Comment: In most of the time, compile error on simple programs might be only a forgotten semicolon or a syntax error. Also it will print the stacktrace of the error.'
In your code the line `string.format` caused the compile error

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what the compile-time error was or which line of your code was causing it, but since you posted a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I just needed to copy your code in order to discover what it was. It is this line:

```java
String Result;
Result = System.out.printf("%03s:%02s:%02s:%02s", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Method [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) returns a `PrintStream` and not a `String`. If you want a `String`, use method [format](http://format)

So your code should be...

```java
String Result;
Result = String.format("%03s:%02s:%02s:%02s", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
System.out.printf(Result);
```

Also, according to [java coding conventions](https://gist.github.com/goldbattle/9283399), variable names - like `Result` - should start with a lower-case letter, i.e. `result`.